# Android: Thread.sleep( ) not working

Tags: java, android, android-animation

In my android app, I want to apply an `animation` on some `imageViews` with implementing delay. When the 1st `imageView` is animated 50%, i want to start `animation` of the second `imageView` and goes on like this.

I used `Thread.sleep()` method for this.

```
public void showImage() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    final Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Home.this,R.anim.myanimation);



    image_1.setImageUrl(links[0]); 
    image_2.setImageUrl(links[1]); 
    image_3.setImageUrl(links[2]);
    image_4.setImageUrl(links[3]);

    image_5.setImageUrl(links[4]); 
    image_6.setImageUrl(links[5]); 
    image_7.setImageUrl(links[0]); 
    image_8.setImageUrl(links[1]); 
    //System.out.println("me");

    image_1_layer.setAnimation(anim); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    image_2_layer.setAnimation(anim); 
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    image_3_layer.setAnimation(anim);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
     image_4_layer.setAnimation(anim); 
     Thread.sleep(5000);

     image_5_layer.setAnimation(anim);
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     image_6_layer.setAnimation(anim);
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     image_7_layer.setAnimation(anim);
     Thread.sleep(5000);
     image_8_layer.setAnimation(anim);
     Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

But when it run the app, it delay before starting any `animation` and then paralally animate all the `imageViews`. how can I start to animate the next `imageView` after 5 seconds of the previous `imageView`'s `animation`?

I called the above `showImage()` method from the override method `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: you are blocking the ui thread. please stop doing that.

Comment: Set yourself an asynchronous timer which will call a callback

Comment: You *can't* use `Thread.sleep` in the UI thread for this. This stops the thread from maintaining your UI.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Thread.sleep` is an incorrect way of achieving what you want. You should take a look at   the [`Animation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class, specifically the [`setStartTime`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setStartTime%28long%29).

You can either construct different animation objects with different (compounded) start times and apply all of them to the views or you can listen to animation events using [`setAnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29)